# Scope of properties in Javascript Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am receiving this error in my console. Error is happening within my for loop Not sure why but when I console.log(manchesterUnited.[0].salary); I get not errors. I am new to JS so it could be something minor. **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'salary' of undefined.**

```
var footballer = function(name, position, age, salary, number) {
  this.name = name;
  this.position = position;
  this.age = age;
  this.salary = salary;
  this.number = number;
}

var manchesterUnited = [];
manchesterUnited[0] = new footballer("Zlatan", "striker", 37, 20, 9);
manchesterUnited[1] = new footballer("Rooney", "forward", 33, 15, 10);

var totalSalary = 0;

for(var i = 0; i <= manchesterUnited.length; i++){
    totalSalary = manchesterUnited[i].salary + totalSalary;
}

console.log(totalSalary);
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the for loop, you have:

```
i <= manchesterUnited.length
```

It should just be:

```
i < manchesterUnited.length
```

Comment: You might add the explanation that indicies start at 0 and thus the last element will be at `array.length - 1`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change this

```
     for(var i = 0; i <= manchesterUnited.length; i++){
           totalSalary = manchesterUnited[i].salary + totalSalary;
     }
```

To this

```
      for(var i = 0; i < manchesterUnited.length; i++){
            totalSalary = manchesterUnited[i].salary + totalSalary;
      }`
```

The reason being that the `<=` operator causes you to pass beyond the length of your array by 1.